# pwmconfig/fancontrol error

Tags: asus, 18.10, fancontrol

I am attempting to get my fans under control on my ASUS B350M M/B running Ubuntu 18.10. Fans are running at 100% nonstop, and of course this problem does not exist when running Windows. I have set up pwmconfig for fancontrol. I have tried using pwmconfig to automatically generate a fancontrol config file, and I have tried to edit the config file hoping to get this error solved with no luck. When I run `sudo fancontrol` I *always* get the following output:

```
Loading configuration from /etc/fancontrol ...
grep: /etc/fancontrol: Is a directory
grep: /etc/fancontrol: Is a directory
grep: /etc/fancontrol: Is a directory
grep: /etc/fancontrol: Is a directory
grep: /etc/fancontrol: Is a directory
grep: /etc/fancontrol: Is a directory
grep: /etc/fancontrol: Is a directory
grep: /etc/fancontrol: Is a directory
grep: /etc/fancontrol: Is a directory
grep: /etc/fancontrol: Is a directory
grep: /etc/fancontrol: Is a directory
Some mandatory settings missing, please check your config file!
```

So the problem seems to be that my config file is apparently missing some "mandatory settings", yet as far as I can tell it is not.
My fancontrol config file saved as /etc/fancontrol/pwmcfg.gvA0m0UuMG contains the following:

```
# Configuration file generated by pwmconfig, changes will be lost
INTERVAL=2
DEVPATH=hwmon0=devices/platform/it87.656
DEVNAME=hwmon0=it8655
FCTEMPS=hwmon0/pwm1=hwmon0/temp2_input hwmon0/pwm3=hwmon0/temp1_input
FCFANS=hwmon0/pwm1=hwmon0/fan1_input hwmon0/pwm3=hwmon0/fan3_input
MINTEMP=hwmon0/pwm1=20 hwmon0/pwm3=20
MAXTEMP=hwmon0/pwm1=60 hwmon0/pwm3=60
MINSTART=hwmon0/pwm1=150 hwmon0/pwm3=190
MINSTOP=hwmon0/pwm1=0 hwmon0/pwm3=90
```

Does anyone have any ideas or work-arounds that may work for this situation? My goal is to get fancontrol working so that my fans can work at a reasonable speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/etc/fancontrol is supposed to be a file, not a directory.

```
sudo mv /etc/fancontrol/pwmcfg.gvA0m0UuMG /tmp/
sudo rmdir /etc/fancontrol
sudo mv /tmp/pwmcfg.gvA0m0UuMG /etc/fancontrol
```

Answer (score 2):

First, I'd recommend booting to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and see if the fans behave there. If they run fast, you may wish to check your BIOS for fan control settings.

---

It doesn't appear that `pwmconfig` is supported on 18.10.

To run `fancontrol`, you need `lm-sensors`.

I'd recommend `thermald` instead of the above...

---

To install `thermald`...

- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install thermald

`Thermald` comes with a default configuration file at `/etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml` that will control most computers, but may need to be customized for some computers. See `man thermal-conf.xml` for some details and examples. Once one has modified the configuration file, stop `thermald` and restart it:

```
sudo service thermald restart
```

After installing thermald, I'd stop the `thermald` process, and run it manually as `sudo thermald --no-daemon` to watch its actions in real time. This real time info can be used to create your own customized thermal-conf.xml file. See `man thermald` for more information.

```
sudo service thermald stop
sudo thermald --no-daemon --loglevel=debug
```

You can search for `thermald` here on Ask Ubuntu to see what previous answers there are.

A good starter reference is at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/ThermalIssues